# Android org.json.JSONException: No value for id

Tags: android

I know that there are several questions posted on here with the same topic and error, but none of them indicate the same problem as mine, so I decided to post my question here, hoping that someone would help me point out the cause. Here's the code:

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
       Constants.URL_LOGIN,
       new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
       progressDialog.dismiss();
       try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
       if (!jsonObject.getBoolean("status")) {
    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
     .userLogin(
     jsonObject.getInt("id"),
     jsonObject.getString("username"),
     jsonObject.getString("email")
     );
    //                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserActivity.class));
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

And this is the JSON response

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Login successfully!",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "28",
            "name": "Rr",
            "username": "rr",
            "password": "rr"

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: why dont use retrofit it is easier

Comment: I'll use that but first i want to use it.

Comment: for this condition if (!jsonObject.getBoolean("status")) and your json you will not get any data at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `id`, `username` and `email` are placed into `data` object. And the data contains an array of objects. So you need to get the `jsonObject` from the data array and then you can find the value of `id`, `username` and `email`.

Try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray dataArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")
JSONObject dataObject = dataArr.getJSONObject(0)

   if (jsonObject.getBoolean("status")) {
      SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
      .userLogin(
       dataObject.getString("id"),
       dataObject.getString("username"),
       dataObject.getString("email")
   );
   ...
}
```

Update the whole code that you provided in this question. The whole code should be like this

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
   Constants.URL_LOGIN,
   new Response.Listener<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(String response) {
     progressDialog.dismiss();
   try {
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

   if (jsonObject.getBoolean("status")) {
       JSONArray dataArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")
       JSONObject dataObject = dataArr.getJSONObject(0)
       SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                        .userLogin(
                         dataObject.getString("id"),
                         dataObject.getString("username"),
                         dataObject.getString("email")
                        );
 //   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserActivity.class));
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: when i login with write credential i got successful message which is in php api but with wrong credential i got nothing except this `org.json.JSONException: No value for id`

Comment: For wrong credentials, you shouldn't get the value of id in the jsonObject. No issue about this. Please check the value of status. If the status is true then you have id value.

Comment: but when i replace the toast with Intent to send the user on profileActivity then error pop up as `org.json.JSONException: No value for id`

Comment: in question i've commented `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserActivity.class));` line but when i uncomment it then i get the same error

Comment: man i'm not even getting a toast of "Invalid username or password!" when i enter wrong email or password. but i gott the toast when i enter write email and password

Comment: @MansoorMalik please check the whole code. Replace your code by this and check.

Comment: as now I'm getting toast when i enter wrong credential but by entering write credential i got the error ` No value for email`

Comment: `email` value does not contain in your data responsibly.  you can only have the id, name, username and password value. Wha it would be `email` of `name`?. If name then just replace `email` to `name` in  `dataObject.getString("email")` to `dataObject.getString("name")`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

log the jsonObject , It will probably get the "data" array which you need to access it to get "id" value

Comment: how i'll achieve this

Comment: Log.d("JSONOBJECT",jsonObject)

Comment: so what next ? this is not the solution of my question

Comment: It's the answer but @Manoj Mohanty solved it already , As you have to get the data Json array first then you can access the id key from it

Comment: i didnt get what is `j.getJSONArray("data");` and i'm getting error on j

Comment: How ?! you are accessing it already ?! just replace the three lines  jsonObject.getInt("id"),
     jsonObject.getString("username"),
     jsonObject.getString("email") with jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array = j.getJSONArray("data");
```

//reason to do 0 because only object is available

```
JSONObject dataObject = array.getJSONObject(0)

 dataObject.getInt("id")
 dataObject.getString("username"),
 dataObject.getString("email")
```

Comment: j is the jsonObject --> JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);